# how to use wmode=transparent in firefox?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flash, browser, cross-browser

I made a webapp where I need html content to popup on top of the swf objects I have. I ended up using the swfobject setting wmode: "transparent" which works fine in all browsers (Chrome, safari, IE) except firefox. In firefox I can't click the flash buttons, i tried to remove wmode=transparent and, of course, I can click any button I need (all browsers)... but this way I can't put my html content on top...

How can I solve this ?

Cheers,
Ze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NEVER use wmode: transparent if you don't really want transparency. It has some nasty performance side effects. Use wmode: opaque instead.

Check out this link for more help: http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting a z-index on mouseover?